# cubic bezier setting for small animation

Tags: css, animation

hey guys i have a simple animation and i would like to make a small correction ,

heres what i have so far :

HTML :

```
<div class="animated"></div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}
.animated {
    animation-name: cst-animation;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes cst-animation {
    0% {
        transform:translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

now this works just fine , but the effect only shows when moving from 0% to 100& I.E. when the animation starts the animation is 3 secound and moves from 50px to 0px , and that exactly what i have coded the animation to be , when the animation repeats (since the iteration count is set to infinite) , theres a abrupt shift from 0px to 50px , how do i stop that from happening ?

Also My **secound Question** :

i have seen `cubic-bezier`s inside keyframes being set as follows :

```
@keyframes cst-animation{

                0% , 100%{
                    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.220, 0.855); 
   -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.220, 0.855); 
     -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.220, 0.855); 
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.220, 0.855); /* custom */
                }
                0%{
                    transform:translate3d(50px ,0,0);
                }
                100%{
                    transform:translate3d(0 ,0,0);
                }
            }
```

is there a different way of doing that rather than :

```
0,100%{
   // my custom cubic bezier
}
```

fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e0d4nqqg/)

i am new to CSS-3 , so i would really appreciate any help .

Comment: you need to include vendor prefixes:[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/e0d4nqqg/2/) but please include what you're exactly looking to do. [to make it alternate, see here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/e0d4nqqg/3/)

Comment: @jbutler483 is it this line doing the trick `animation-direction: alternate;` doing the trick ??

Comment: Yes - that makes it 'reverse' when animation finishes

Comment: @jbutler483 AWESSSSSOOOOOOOOOMEEEEEE !!! YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEYYYYYYYYYYYY . Thanks .

Comment: np glad I could help